# Find the duplicate sentence with count after removing some content in linux

Tags: linux

I am fresher in Linux command

In my log file, I have saved the content like that

`2016-08-11 11:47:19 To: saravana@adodis.com   ==> /var/log/testmail.php
2016-08-11 11:47:41 To: sathiyasaravanababu91@gmail.com   ==> /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/hostingraja_info/testmail.php
2016-08-11 11:48:06 To: sathiyasaravanababu91@gmail.com   ==> /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/hostingraja_info/testmail.php`

I have used the below command

`sort mail_php.log | uniq -c`

that produce the following output

```
  1 2016-08-11 11:47:19 To: saravana@adodis.com   ==> /var/log/testmail.php
  1 2016-08-11 11:47:41 To: sathiyasaravanababu91@gmail.com   ==> /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/hostingraja_info/testmail.php
  1 2016-08-11 11:48:06 To: sathiyasaravanababu91@gmail.com   ==> /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/hostingraja_info/testmail.php
```

but I need the following result

```
  1 To: saravana@adodis.com   ==> /var/log/testmail.php
  2 To: sathiyasaravanababu91@gmail.com   ==> /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/hostingraja_info/testmail.php
```

is it possible via a command ? or else needed to write a shell script?

Could you please help me ?

Comment: so basically u donot need the time column right ?

Comment: Yes, Absolutely correct @Ansh

Comment: Is it possible via a command ? or else needed to write a shell script? but that won't affect the original file too.

Comment: its very much possible by shell command let me check if  i can give a quick solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, its a basic step to start with:

```
awk '{print $3 " " $4 " " $5 " "  $6}' mail_php.log | uniq -c
```

Comment: Thank you @Ansh. It's working fine and understand easily

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with the `cut` command :

```
cat mail_php.log | cut -d" " -f3- | sort | uniq -c
```

as you are a newbie, I suggest you have a look at the `awk` command also.

Comment: Thank you so much @julien. It's working fine :) . Let me know the working flow this code that helpful to my understanding